# [vue-apollo]:An error has occured for query getTeam

Tags: graphql, vue-apollo

I am working vue-apollo, currently I am having issues:

#### Workspace.vue

```html
<script>
    import { GetTeam } from '../constants/query.gql'
    export default  {
        name: 'Workspace',
        data() {
            return {
                getTeam: {}
            }
        },
        apollo: {
            getTeam: {
                query: GetTeam
            }
        }
   }
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

#### query.gql

```
query GetTeam {
    getTeam {
       id
       name
    }
}
```

**I am facing the below error**

> [vue-apollo]:An error has occured for query getTeam

Is there a way to fix the issue?

```js
//resolvers.js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
        async getTeam(_, args, context) {
            const userId = getUserId(context)
            const user = await User.findById(userId)
            return await Team.findById(user.team)
        }
}

//schema.graphql

type Team {
    id: String!
    name: String!
}

type User {
  ......
}
```

Comment: add full message of error to your question

Comment: Hi @barbsan message error:
[vue-apollo]:An error has occured for query **'getTeam'**

Comment: That's all? No callstack?

Comment: @barbsan This is query **getTeam**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running:

```
npm install --no-save apollo-utilities@1.0.22
```

Solved the issue for me. See https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4125